# Optional parentheses in Verilog event control statements?

Tags: language-lawyer, verilog, system-verilog

Is the following a valid Verilog module?

```
module test;

logic a;

initial @a;

endmodule
```

Verilog simulators seem to think so -- but strictly speaking is this an extension of the official Verilog syntax?

The relevant part of the syntax of event control statements is defined as follows in the SystemVerilog-2017 standard:

```
event_control ::=
   @ hierarchical_event_identifier
 | @ ( event_expression )
 | @*
 | @ (*)
 | @ ps_or_hierarchical_sequence_identifier
```

I don't see where `@a` would fit into the above. The `event_expression` case requires parentheses, and `hierarchical_event_identifier` seems to be for named events and `ps_or_hierarchical_sequence_identifier` for sequences, whereas here `a` is a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a valid Verilog module.

In IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 9.4.2 *Event control*, there is an example:

> The following example shows illustrations of edge-controlled
> statements:
>
> **@r** rega = regb; // controlled by any value change in the reg **r**

It shows `@r`, where `r` is a `reg` variable.  `r` is considered a simplified version of a `hierarchical_event_identifier` without the leading dot-separated hierarchical path.  Section A.9.3 *Identifiers* shows that `hierarchical_event_identifier` is the same as `hierarchical_identifier`, which is declared as:

> hierarchical_identifier ::= [ $root . ] { identifier
> constant_bit_select . } identifier

Everything before the right-most `identifier` is optional.  *Annex A
(normative) Formal syntax* mentions:

```
 — Square brackets ( [ ] ) enclose optional items.
 — Braces ( { } ) enclose items that can be repeated zero or more times.
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! From the standard: "The value changes on nets and variables can be used as events to trigger the execution of a statement. This is known as detecting an implicit event." So we are not actually referring to a variable, but the implicit event associated with the value changes on the variable -- so that's why it makes sense to parse `a` (in my example) and `r` (in the example from the standard) as a `hierarchical_event_identifier`s. I.e., the following assumption from my initial question is incorrect: "`hierarchical_event_identifier` seems to be for named events".